# Кастомизация календаря datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Можно ли в календаре datepicker через js выделить какую-нибудь определённую дату и например задать другой цвет текста ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример на фотографии, только нужно выделить не ряды, а определённую дату

Примечание: тёмно-синем выделена текущая дату, а ещё нужна дополнительная дата со своим выделением  ( цвета пример )

Comment: В чём проблема найти ноду с нужной data-date и поменять ей class?

Comment: хоть написали бы, какой это datepicker

Comment: если речь про bootstrap datepicker, то `beforeShowDay`  в помощь

Comment: @teran jQuery UI

Comment: как ни странно там тоже есть `beforeShowDay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

предполагаю, что вчерашнюю дату можно выделить как-то так

```js
let d = new Date();
let yts = d.setHours(0,0,0,0) -  24*3600*1000;

$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d){      
      if(d.getTime() == yts){
          return [true, 'wow', 'hey!'];
      }
      return [true];
    }
});
```

```css
.wow > a {
 
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```